# Validate multiple select groups with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my js fiddle link :
http://jsfiddle.net/m4tyC/

i have multiple select tags and i want to validate on submit if for example

at least if one of the size1 and color1 and Qty1 is selected in the first group and if one is selected i want to validate the others and in the same time if at least one group is selected the form can submit and if the user selected one option from the second group i do the same validation type for the second group of size2 , color2 , ...

i appreciate any help with that , i use jquery in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (form will submit only when at least one row is completely selected)

```
$(function(){
    $('#frm_productOrder').on('submit', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var f=$(this);    
        var invalid=false, selected=0;
        $('.selects').each(function(){
        var row=$(this);
        var items=0;
        $('select', row).each(function(){
            var t=$(this);
            var selectedIndex=t.prop("selectedIndex");
            if(selectedIndex) items++;
        });
        if(items==3) selected++;
        if(items>0 && items<3) invalid=true;
        items=0;
        });
        if(selected>0 && !invalid) f[0].submit();
        else alert('Please fill up the form correctly');       
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/m4tyC/1/)

Comment: i applied this solution and it worked just fine i have another thing that i wanted to add to the code i appreciate too if u can help me with ! :

Comment: i want to addClass say: ".invalid" to the unselected <select> in the row so i can highlight the invalid fields when its invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some JQuery code.  You can figure out how to submit the form on success by yourself:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event)
    {
        var is_valid = true;// for avoiding alerting in loop
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).find("select").each(function(){ //usually default is the first
            if(!$(this).attr("selected"))
            {
                $("#"+$(this).attr("id")).each(function()
                {
                    if($(this).find("option:first").attr("selected"))
                    {
                        is_valid = false;
                    }
                });                             
            }
        });
        if( !is_valid )
            alert("Please make sure all values are set for row!");
        });
});
```

​

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByHM7/6/).  There are some bugs too, but you can work that out.